Configuring Namespace and Tenant for Spring-Pulsar
Is there a way in Spring-Pulsar to change the namespace and tenant? By default, Spring-Pulsar goes to public tenant and default namespace. I want to use a property or application.yml to set a default tenant and namespace.
Right now, I'm manually creating a full topic name for producer and consumer, but it would be much nicer to have this be automaticly configured via the yml.

There is not currently a way to do this but it is an excellent feature request and there is now a ticket to track its progress here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-pulsar/issues/756
